# How can I correctly use lists as descriptions to items of description lists?

Tags: lists, enumitem, description

I am writing a manual using description lists to list off GUI menu items with their subordinated parameters. An undesired effect occurs when embedding lists as the description of an item of the superior list. The embedded list does not appear on the next line.

1. I would like to know why.
2. I would like to know how to fix it.

I tried to use `\null`, `\phantom{a}`, `\vphantom{a}`, and `\hphantom{a}` after a superior `\item` to no avail.

## Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}


\NewDocumentEnvironment{parameters}{}
    {%
    \small
    \setlist[description]{font=\tt,nosep,labelwidth=20pt,leftmargin=30pt,}
    \begin{description}
    }%
    {%
    \end{description}
    }

\begin{document}
    
\begin{description}%<- Superior
\item [Apple]%<- Superior
   \begin{parameters}%<- Inferior
       \item [Citris] 0%<- Inferior
       \item [ExcludeFromFridge] 1%<- Inferior
       \item [ConsumeCold]%<- Inferior
   \end{parameters}%<- Inferior
\item [Beer]%<- Superior
   \begin{parameters}%<- Inferior
       \item [Citris] 0%<- Inferior
       \item [ExcludeFromFridge] 0%<- Inferior
       \item [ConsumeCold] 1%<- Inferior
   \end{parameters}%<- Inferior
\end{description}%<- Superior

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## Desired Output

(without DUMMY text)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `xparse` for this case and the facilities of `enumitem` are best suited. I have defined a new list `parameters` using `\newlist` (of `enumitem`). Also same `enumitem` provides `before` key using which, we can force a new line.  We have to tell TeX to change the vertical mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{parameters}{description}{1}
\setlist[parameters]{before={\mbox{}\leavevmode},font=\ttfamily,nosep,labelwidth=20pt,leftmargin=30pt,}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}%<- Superior
\item [Apple]%<- Superior
   \begin{parameters}%<- Inferior
       \item [Citris] 0%<- Inferior
       \item [ExcludeFromFridge] 1%<- Inferior
       \item [ConsumeCold]%<- Inferior
   \end{parameters}%<- Inferior
\item [Beer]%<- Superior
   \begin{parameters}%<- Inferior
       \item [Citris] 0%<- Inferior
       \item [ExcludeFromFridge] 0%<- Inferior
       \item [ConsumeCold] 1%<- Inferior
   \end{parameters}%<- Inferior
\end{description}%<- Superior

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used `xparse` for fun. That has become my standard for creating commands and environments. Great that you demonstrate an alternative way to create a list environment using `enumitem`! Thanks! What exactly is put into the `\mbox{}`? It almost looks like functional programming, because I do not see a value being sent to it and it looks like I am sending a function as a parameter.

Comment: Also, maybe you know why `\topsep=0pt` does not remove the white space above the list. It would be nice to control that precisely.

Comment: @macmadness86  try negative values for `topsep` like `topsep=-1ex`. And `\mbox{}` is the habit that saves life. Nothing is put in to it but it starts the line. In this case it works without it.